# Location for "import" code in the rails MVC scheme of directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, structure

## Background

We are using these locations as per the Rails standard:

- `app/models` for models (including `app/models/concerns` to avoid the `app/models/*.rb` files getting too fat)
- `app/controllers` (including concerns) for lean controllers
- `app/views` as usual
- `app/view_models` for "view models" (Ruby code that is specific to an association between a view and a model, but cannot really exist separately, so cannot really be put into the model or the view)
- `lib` for code that is not calling into `app`, but is called from `app`; for things that are really not domain-specific to our application. These are potential candidates for getting extracted into their own gems, if they were to be re-used in other apps.

So far so good, I believe this is all pretty common.

## Problem

There is one specific type of code that I am not really sure where to put. This is code related to importing data. This may, for example, be code which processes some XML and does several different actions on the models, but may also be things like code parsing an Excel file, or a class that pulls data from some webservice). Let's see where we could put that:

- `app/models/concerns` - this is where we have that now. But that code is not really representing a model; it is representing a state-changing XML (in this example). It will strongly *interact* with models, but is not themselves a model; a strong expectation for us is that code in `app/models` is often used by other classes (i.e., by controllers, views...), but the kind of code we are talking about now is not really doing that.
- `app/controllers` - the part that does any actual file handling and such lives there, this is OK. The processing of the XML data structures does not belong there.
- `app/views` - nope.
- `lib` - nope. The handling of the XML in this example is very domain/app specific.

## Question

Where do you put such code? Do you have an `app/import` subtree? Does it live in the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked your approach of architecture and folder structure, so couldn't get past your post :)

I think, that app subfolder is definitely the correct place to keep such classes. In our projects we have app/services, app/decorators, app/facades (as an another realization of view_models that we took from Sandi Metz).

Several weeks ago we faced the very same logic, as you and we decided to store it in app/parsers. In your case I would think about app/importers or smth like this.

So my general opinion is that your initial direction is correct for sure.

Comment: So you are pretty generous with new `app/*` subdirectories? Guess that makes sense after all.

Comment: I think that any type of your architecture entity can live in it's own app subfolder